# Laravel 5.4: Override default class / function

Tags: customization, laravel-5.4, vendor

I'm using the default `Auth::routes()` of Laravel.

Due of some customization, I need to change the `redirectTo` URL and the `showLoginForm()` as well as `login()` function.

What's the best way to do this without touching the files in the `vendor/` directory? Extending?

Comment: you can do something like `protected $redirectTo = /routewhereyourlocation ` and then redirect this route to your `showLoginForm()` function

Comment: The default routes redirect me to `/home` and I want to set my own, but I can't even find the line, where it redirects to this line.